# Nest can't resolve dependencies of the testString

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs

**Issue:**

Getting below issue while executing unit test case

*Nest can't resolve dependencies of the testString (?). Please make sure that the argument SECRET_MANAGER_SERVICE at index [0 ] is available in the SecretManagerServiceModule context.*

**Error Logs:**

SecretsManagerServiceModule › #forFeature() › Shold have plain string secret (without id)

```
Nest can't resolve dependencies of the testString (?). Please make sure that the argument SECRET_MANAGER_SERVICE at index [0] is available in the SecretManagerServiceModule context.

Potential solutions:
- If SECRET_MANAGER_SERVICE is a provider, is it part of the current SecretManagerServiceModule?
- If SECRET_MANAGER_SERVICE is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within SecretManagerServiceModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing SECRET_MANAGER_SERVICE */ ]
  })

  at Injector.lookupComponentInParentModules (node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:190:19)
  at Injector.resolveComponentInstance (node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:146:33)
  at resolveParam (node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:100:38)
      at async Promise.all (index 0)
  at Injector.resolveConstructorParams (node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:115:27)
  at Injector.loadInstance (node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:79:9)
  at Injector.loadProvider (node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:36:9)
      at async Promise.all (index 3)
  at InstanceLoader.createInstancesOfProviders (node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/instance-loader.js:41:9)
  at node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/instance-loader.js:27:13
```

**Code:**

Github Link: https://github.com/bhushan629/aws

```
test('Shold have plain string secret (without id)', async () => {
      const response: AWS.SecretsManager.GetSecretValueResponse = {
        SecretString: 'hello',
      };

      AWSMock.mock('SecretsManager', 'getSecretValue', Promise.resolve(response));
      const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
        imports: [
          SecretManagerServiceModule.forRoot({}),
          SecretManagerServiceModule.forFeature({
            confiiguration: [{ secretName: 'testString', secretType: 'plain' }],
          }),
        ],
      }).compile();
      const plainString = module.get('testString');
      expect(plainString).toEqual('hello');
    });
```

I have tried to follow same structure as nestjs/mongoose (https://github.com/nestjs/mongoose)
but its not working for me. anyone know what is problem with this code?

**How to Use:**

app.module.ts : This will initialize SecretsManager

```
@Module({
  imports: [SecretManagerServiceModule.forRoot({})],
})
class AppModule {}
```

sample.module.ts : once secrets manager initialize we can use forFeature function to inject secrets to any providers

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    SecretManagerServiceModule.forFeature({
      confiiguration: [{ secretName: 'testString', secretType: 'plain' }],
    }),
  ],
  providers: [SampleService],
})
class SampleModule {}
```

sample.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
class SampleService {
  constructor(@Inject('testString') testStr: string) {}
}
```

Comment: Can you show what your `forRoot` and `forFeature` functions do? And any services that are injecting providers for use?

Comment: i have updated the description on how to use this.

Comment: i have found the solution. i forgot to mark module as Global thats why it was not working . but now its all ok

Comment: `confiiguration` is spelled wrong as well in your sample.module.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Edit 01/06/2020

After taking a look at the code and the discussion we briefly had on discord (jmcdo29), the solution is to mark the `SecretManagerServiceModule` and `@Global()` so that after running `SecretManagerServiceModule.forRoot()` the provider is still available when you run `SecretManagerServiceModule.forFeature()`.

You may want to look into make a `core` module similar to ow NestJS does for Mongoose and TypeORM, just to keep some of the code a bit cleaner/more reasonable to understand. Glad you were able to find the solution :)

---

From what I can see by the code you've provided, you are trying to inject the value related to the injection token `testString`. As I cannot see what tokens you are providing in your modules, all I can say is that you need to make sure that you have something in either your `forRoot` or `forFeature` you need to have in your `providers` array something along the lines of the following:

```
{
  provide: 'testString',
  useValue: theValueYouWantToInject
}
```

If you need more help, more code will need to be seen. Specifically, how your `SecretsManagerModule` `forRoot` and `forFeature` methods work and what you are providing as injection tokens

Comment: forRoot function creating the provider

{
provide: 'SECRET_MANAGER_SERVICE',
  useValue: new AWS.SecretsManager()
}

And forFeature function is use to create the provider testString. but to create this provider i need to inject "SECRET_MANAGER_SERVICE" provider. please check this [code](https://github.com/bhushan629/aws/blob/master/src/services/secrets-manager/secrets.provider.ts) .

but nestjs somehow not able to inject SECRET_MANAGER_SERVICE